# Customize sidebar in magento for specific page

Tags: magento

I just installed magento along with it's sample data. I set the about page to use 2 columns with a left sidebar and added a custom widget. The widget is being displayed below the default blocks the first one is Compare Products, below that is My Cart, below that is Popular Tags. And below those three is my custom static block/widget.

How would I customize the left side for this specific page? I'd like to remove the default blocks it's showing and only use my widget.

Thanks

Comment: how I do this at product page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the code below to work. If there's a better method / best practice way of doing it i'd like to hear. Thanks

```
<reference name="left">
    <remove name="cart_sidebar"></remove>
    <remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar"></remove>
    <remove name="tags_popular"></remove>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 1):

Open "About Us" page in admin,

Go to `Design` tab->`Page Layout` to place layout code.Here is an example

**Update**

```
<reference name="left">
  <action method="unsetChild">tags_popular<name></name></action> <!-- remove tags -->
  <block type="cms/block" name="yourblock">
    <action method="setBlockId">
     <block_id>side_block</block_id>
    </action>
   </block>
</reference>
```

Comment: Keeping the Layout set to 2 Column with left bar I still see the default blocks. Should I be changing the Layout? Does the code you gave just override the default sidebar?

Comment: Yes.This will override default sidebar.I have updated my answer.